# Time Limit Exceeded. Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что поправить в коде, чтоб он проходил по времени.
Вот условие задачи:

> You are given an array of n numbers and q queries. For each query you
>   have to print the floor of the expected value(mean) of the subarray
>   from L to R.
>   *Input:*
>     First line contains two integers N and Q denoting number of array elements and number of queries. Next line contains N space
>   seperated integers denoting array elements. Next Q lines contain two
>   integers L and R(indices of the array).
>   *Output:*
>     print a > single integer denoting the answer.
>    Constraints:
>    1<= N ,Q,L,R <= 10^6 1<= Array elements <= 10^9
>   *

Вот мое решение:

```
N, Q = map(int, input().split())
array = list(map(int, input().split()))
for i in range(Q):
    L, R = map(int, input().split())
    print((sum(array[:R]) - sum(array[:L-1])) // (R - L + 1))
```

Comment: удалось увеличить немного, используя sys.stdin и используя перед выводом переменную для результата, однако тест по времени не проходит...

Comment: `array[:R]` и `array[:L-1]` каждый раз делают копию части списка. Попробуйте использовать [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

Comment: вопрос решил созданием нового списка, в котором накопил суммы элементов исходного списка, и требуемые суммы я уже брал готовые, а не считал в цикле... ну и остатки кода позаимствовал у других

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
N, Q = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
array = [int(i) for i in sys.stdin.readline().split()]
arr = [array[0]]
for i in range(1, N):
    arr.append(arr[i-1] + array[i])
for i in range(Q):
    L, R = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    if (L - 2) >= 0:
        res = (arr[R-1] - arr[L-2]) // (R - L + 1)
    else:
        res = arr[R - 1] // (R - L + 1)
    print(res)
```

итог который приняла система)